# what's the difference between running a exit command inside a file and a terminal

Tags: linux, bash, exit-code

if I run `exit` command in terminal, then the terminal will exit and close itself.
if I run the following command then terminal wont close itself (note the use of `exit` command in if-else command:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
if [ $a -eq 1 ]
then
echo i am true
exit
else
echo i am false
fi
```

NOTE: I use if-else condition in above code just for demonstration, it has nothing to do with my question.

Please comment if you think there is something wrong with this question, please don't rate it -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executing the script invokes another copy of the script interpreter. It is *this* interpreter (in this case, bash) that exits, returning control back to the executing program.

Comment: BTW, if you `source your-script`, it is running in the same shell, and your shell would exit,hence your terminal would close.